# Applescript for showing/hiding menu bar in full screen

Tags: applescript

I am trying to write an applescript to hide the menubar in fullscreen when i watch movies. Otherwise i want it always turned on. I have come so far as to reveal the tab "Dock & Menu Bar" but i don't know how to click the right checkbox.
The following code is what i have come up with but as stated it isn't much.

tell application "System Preferences"
activate
set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.dock"
end tell

For reference: I want to click the checkbox "Automaticly hide and show the menu bar in full screen"

Comment: Your task is of little interest for automation. Because the players have a setting "Run application in full screen mode". I use VLC for example. Just set the checkbox and restart the application (you only need to restart once - to remember the settings by the application).

Answer (score 0):

When any application is in "Full Screen Mode", the menu bar is automatically hidden.  However, if the app is "Zoomed", this following **AppleScript** code will toggle the **autohide menu bar** to on or off.

```
tell application "System Events"
    if not autohide menu bar of dock preferences then
        set autohide menu bar of dock preferences to true
    else
        set autohide menu bar of dock preferences to false
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: I usually have the menubar shown in Full Screen Mode, but want wo hide it when i am watching a movie. Your script works, but i want it to click the button below. Do you have a solution for that as well? Adding "in full screen" into the code doesn't seen to work as "in" seems to be an identifier in applescript.